# How do I auto-register/resolve services by their interface?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

I'm developing a MVC .NET Core 3/Angular/Entity Framework application.  My application will likely have a lot of repositories in it. To support this I would like to resolve the service (repository) by its default interface (i.e. I request IRepository and the DI resolver gives me Repository).  I know I can manually wire up the dependencies, but all of my DI frameworks in the past have had a means of auto-registering/resolving based on patterns or the like.

For example, with Castle Winsdor I could wire it up like this:

```
container.Register(Classes
    .FromAssemblyNamed("MyLibary.Repository")
    .InNamespace("MyLibrary.Repository")
    .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
    .LifestyleTransient()
);
```

This would register all classes in the MyLibrary.Repository namespace to be resolved by their default interfaces they implement.  How can this be done in .NET Core 3?  If this isn't built-in, I'm assuming I will have to use reflection to query all the classes in the assembly, iterate through each class and register it by its interface it implements.

Comment: It is not a feature of the built in DI. You would either need to use reflection or use a 3rd party DI extension container. Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Comment: See [Default service container replacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#default-service-container-replacement) within that same page referenced above. [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) is a popular option that provides this functionality using the default container.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [AutoRegisterDI](https://github.com/JonPSmith/NetCore.AutoRegisterDi) lib to not reinvent a bicycle. It's fast, simple and based on Microsoft Dependency Injection. This [benchmark](https://ipjohnson.github.io/DotNet.DependencyInjectionBenchmarks/) will show you the speed difference.
[And this is the article about how to use it](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-fast-and-automatic-dependency-injection-setup/)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Adding links is great, but adding the important details from them is even better.

Answer (score 2):

Install this package:

**NetCore.AutoRegisterDi**

Add this code to your program.cs:

```
builder.Services.RegisterAssemblyPublicNonGenericClasses()
.Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
.AsPublicImplementedInterfaces(ServiceLifetime.Scoped); // default is Transient
```

If you have a Singleton service , add [RegisterAsSingleton] on top of your service class.

If you want to ignore injection of an particular interface add this line after .Where() :

```
.IgnoreThisInterface<IMyInterface>()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with reflection in c#.first create an extension method like this :

```
public static void AddScopedServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
      
    }
```

and use it in startup.cs  ,ConfigureServices method :  `services.AddScopedServices();`

now to implement this method like this:

```
  var allProviderTypes = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ICartRepository))
            .GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace != null).ToList();

        foreach (var intfc in allProviderTypes.Where(t => t.IsInterface))
        {
            var impl = allProviderTypes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsClass && intfc.Name.Substring(1) == c.Name);
            if (impl != null) serviceCollection.AddScoped(intfc, impl);
        }
```

you just need to put all your interfaces in a namespace and  introduce one of them in this method ,in my case I used ICartRepository ,so it takes all interfaces and search for classes which inherit from that interface.
one point you need to consider is that class names must be like interfacenames without 'I' in the beginning ,like 'CartRepository'

Answer (score 0):

I recently got tired of writing the same old

```
services.AddTransient<IInterface,IImplementation>
```

so I created a simple library to help me auto-register services.

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/Stoyanov8/Serviced).

Register the library in Startup.cs
There are 3 interface -> ITransient, IScoped, ISingleton generic and non-generic versions.

Let's say you want to register service "TestService" as transient.

```
TestService: ITransient<ITestService>, ITestService
```

Inherit **ITransient** interface and its done.

For more detailed information please refer to the Readme section.

Currently it lacks registering services with implementation factory, but it's something I'm willing to do in the near future.